# Login via httpsURLConnection, how to know if successful

Tags: java, android, session-cookies, httpsurlconnection

I am using `httpsURLConnection` to send my `username` and `pw` to a webserver where I want to login myself.

The setup works this is not the problem. The problem is that I want to know if I am successfully loged in.

`responseCode` is not the way to go as it responses with `200` regardless if right or wrong account-informations were passed to the webserver.

My current approach is to see if a `cookie` is returned by the server, if so I know I am logged in on the specific webserver, if not, the credentials were invalid. But I am not sure if this is the common approach. A threat is that the webserver changes this behavior and might return a cookie even when just parsing the `login.php`. Therefore I would not have any validation of my credentials.

Comment: I'm not sure in your case because in SharePoint 2013 Authentication is using NTLM. If you pass in wrong credential it will return 401... This is my post previously... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913269/android-java-to-sharepoint-2013-ntlm-401-unauthorize/31937351#31937351

Comment: you can check it with sessionId

Comment: @nicholas not in my case. As stated, the server responses wit 200 if connection is successful. And a successful connection does not have anything to do wether or not the passed credentials are valid. That is why he returns 200 regardless if right or wrong credentials were passed.

Answer (score 0):

Read the response text from the server and know whether it's success or not,

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(inputLine.contains("yourCheckString"))
                   System.out.println("Login Successfull!");
        }
```